# NSError initialization macro stopped working with recent Clang

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am used to using this macro to initialize `NSError**` arguments:

```
#define INIT_ERROR_IF_NULL(error) error = error ? error : &(NSError*){ nil }
```

This checks the passed `NSError**` argument and if it’s `NULL`, initializes it to a dummy `NSError` so that I don’t have to wrap every `*error` dereference in a conditional. In code, this version:

```
- (void) doFoo: (NSError**) error
{
    if (error) {
        *error = [NSError …];
    }
}
```

…turns into this:

```
- (void) doFoo: (NSError**) error
{
    INIT_ERROR_IF_NULL(error);
    *error = [NSError …];
}
```

I like the approach, it saves branching and makes me write less code (of course I don’t bother when the `error` is being used just once). The problem is that it stopped working in the recent Clang version, as the compiler complains about pointer type mismatch:

```
Pointer type mismatch ('NSError *__autoreleasing *' and 'NSError **')
```

If I change the macro to explicitly cast the resulting anonymous object to `NSError *__autoreleasing*` (the type signatures are getting ridiculous), the compiler complains further, on a different line:

```
Casting 'NSError **' to type 'NSError *__autoreleasing *' changes retain/release properties of pointer
```

Again, the variable in question is a method argument. I don’t understand the issue. What can I do to keep my macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles without errors/warnings:

```
#define INIT_ERROR_IF_NULL(error) error = error ? error : &( NSError __autoreleasing *){ nil }
```